# How do I call Postgres' `Round` from Linq?

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq

I get the error `Numeric value does not fit in a System.Decimal` on a Linq expression where I take a sum of the product of two numbers which in Postgres are represented by `Numeric(100,20)`. The result of this calculation is apparently a `Numeric` with 40 decimals which cannot be cast to a .NET `Decimal` hence the error.

I understand from some SQL experts that I could use `Round(num, 20)` in SQL to fix this, but I do not know how to do this through Linq.

I would like to continue to use Linq and not use raw SQL expressions since I have unit tests that depend on in-memory databases which do not understand raw SQL.

Comment: Maybe anyone knows a better solution, after some researches I couldn't achieve that with pure ef core. I have used `FromSql` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: Thank you! I use `FromSql` in some situations but I would like to keep this code in Linq because of the tests.

Comment: You "have unit tests that depend on in-memory databases", then you are NOT in a simulated production environment - the database at lease must be the same. That will at some point result in a failure.  The requirement of the production environment should drive the test tool requirements. Not as you have it the other way around. (At least IMHO)